# Como percorrer um dicionário que possui valor None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dicionário

Eu tenho um dataframe que possui uma coluna multivalorada. Essa coluna possui um dicionário dentro de uma lista. Pode ser que em alguma linha venha como None ou o dicionário dentro da lista. A ideia é percorrer essa coluna e trazer somente o que não for nulo, no caso o que está na chave 'optionText'.

Para isso, transformei essa coluna em um dicionário para fazer um tratamento dos dados, toda a lista que possui vários dicionários que possuem a chave 'optionText' precisam ser concatenadas em uma só string ou se tiver algum valor em 'optionText' também preciso retornar, porém, quando vou retornar o valor eu recebo uma mensagem de erro.

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Segue um exemplo da coluna transformada em dicionário e o código que faz o tratamento:

```
{0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None, 10: None, 11: None, 12: None, 13: None, 14: None, 15: None, 16: [{'optionId': 18281008, 'optionText': 'SOMETHING', 'optionValue': 0}], 17: None, 18: None, 19: None, 20: None, 21: None, 22: None, 23: None, 24: None, 25: None, 26: None, 27: None, 28: None, 29: None, 30: None, 31: None, 32: None, 33: None, 34: [{'optionId': 18281060, 'optionText': 'SOMETHING', 'optionValue': 0}], 35: [{'optionId': 18281262, 'optionText': 'SOMETHING', 'optionValue': 0}], 36: None, 37: None, 38: None, 39: None, 40: None, 41: None, 42: None, 43: None, 44: None, 45: None, 46: None, 47: None, 48: None, 49: None, 50: [{'optionId': 18281108, 'optionText': 'SOMETHING', 'optionValue': 0}], 51: [{'optionId': 18231299, 'optionText': 'SOMETHING', 'optionValue': None}, {'optionId': 18231300, 'optionText': 'SOMETHING', 'optionValue': None}, {'optionId': 18231301, 'optionText': 'SOMETHING', 'optionValue': None}]}
```

```
dict = df_itens.selectedOptions.to_dict()

def treatmentSelectedOptions(dict):
    texto = ''
    for i in range(len(dict)):
        try:
            if( i < len(dict)-1 ):
                texto = texto + dict[i].get('optionText', '') + ", "
            else:
                texto = texto + dict[i].get('optionText', '')
        except KeyError:
            print('key does not exist in dict')
            dict[i] =  []
        
    return texto
```

Answer (score 1):

"dict" é uma palavra reservada, convém usar outra. Podes verificar se o item é uma lista e depois tens de iterar sobre essa lista e verificar se o item contém a propriedade 'optionText' e se for o último item removemos a vírgula.

```
def treatmentSelectedOptions(d):
    texto = ''
    for i in range(len(d)):
        if type(d[i]) is list:
            for j in range(len(d[i])):
                if (j == len(d[i]) - 1):
                    texto = texto + d[i][j]['optionText']
                else:
                    texto = texto + d[i][j]['optionText'] + ", "
            texto += "\n"
        else:
            print('key does not exist in dict')
            d[i] =  []
        
    return texto
```

Comment: Eu tentei executar aqui e o resultado foi juntar todos os valores em uma string separados por vírgula. Gostaria de saber como ficaria se fosse em cada lista concatenar as strings "optionText" de cada dicionário. Porque cada lista é correspondente a uma linha, então se uma lista é representa uma linha então se tem 3 dicionários dentro deveria concatenar os valores da chave "optionText" e concatenar em uma linha só.

Comment: Editado. Basta adicionar o caratér de nova linha.